# Creating evenly spaced images regardless of size

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am making a photo gallery where all the images are pulled from a MySQL database and displayed on the page using `echo ('<div class="photo"> <img src="' . $row['name'] . '" /> </div>');`. I am trying to get the images to fit inside of a fixed width container and have them all evenly spaced like shown [here](http://www.istockphoto.com/search/text/turtles/filetype/photos/source/basic#124e2f97). I keep having issues with this the images are not evenly spaced vertically. Can someone please help me with this I have included my source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
<?php
require 'DB.php';



    try{      
    $stmt ='SELECT * FROM victoria';
    foreach ($conn->query($stmt) as $row)
        {
        echo ('<div class="photo"> <img src="' . $row['name'] . '" /> </div>');
        }
    }  catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


?>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color: #013FF0;
}

.container {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;

}

.photo{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.photo img{

    width: 250px;
    height: auto;

}
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP as the PHP is irrelevant here. Also, a jsFiddle would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `line-height: 300px;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to `.photo`:

```
.photo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
}

.photo img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/QXGuH/.

Comment: Sorry, please try again.

Comment: nice that helped out a lot but if I want them in a grid so that all images are the same size how would I make the images constrain to a certain dimension without distorting from the original say I wanted to fit the image inside a 100px x 100px box

Comment: I advice to make icons in PHP and store them at the server. Resizing images using CSS is a bad practise. But you can try to use `max-width` and `max-height`.